# Access objects property in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to access email property of user object

```
{"name":"test", "email":"test@test.x"}
```

like this:

```
<input type="text" :placeholder="user.email">
```

When I try to access property in console -> console.log(user.email) everything work's just fine

component code ->

```
<template>
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="smth.php">
        <input type="text" :placeholder="user.email">
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        user: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Component call ->

```
<div class="container">
    <page-profile :user="{{ $user->toJson() }}"></page-profile>
</div>
```

Could you please show me the right way how to access the email property of user object?
Both console and npm watch show no errors.

Comment: Well what is the problem? Do you have an error in the console? Or is it just not displaying? Or something else? What is the concrete problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @FahimAhmed please make sure you aren't overwriting any valid edits

Comment: @JamesCoyle is this fine?

Comment: @PatrickHollweck there should be displayed email of the user in placeholder but isn'ŧ

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <page-profile :user="{{ $user->toJson() }}"></page-profile>
</div>
```

You don't need those curly braces in a property definition. Those are only required in the content of a tag and not an attribute.

I'm also not sure what the `->` arrow is supposed to be doing. Is that from PHP?

You probably want something more like the following:

```html
<div class="container">
    <page-profile :user="$user.toJson()"></page-profile>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is from php. $user is user object from the app backend and {{ $user->toJson()  }} is laravel syntax for echoing variable

Comment: Can you show the rendered version of that code instead then? Your question doesn't mention backend rendering at all.

Comment: Yes, because I have thought that error was on the frontend part. I don't really understand how is it possible but object was missing those parameters even though they were accessible through the console ... Sorry for taking your time with my stupid mistake :/